# wxWidget configure: cannot guess build type

Tags: c++, build, wxwidgets

I'm trying to build wxWidget on Windows following [this](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started) tutorial
. But when typed ../configure --enable-unicode --enable-debug -- --enable-monolithic --disable-shared, the output is a lot of "Segmentation fault" messages:

```
$ ./configure --enable-unicode --enable-debug --enable-monolithic --disable-shared
./configure: line 427:  3224 Segmentation fault      expr a : '\(a\)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure: line 1492:  2560 Segmentation fault      expr "x$ac_useropt" : ".*[^-+._$as_cr_alnum]" > /dev/null
./configure: line 1492:  2452 Segmentation fault      expr "x$ac_useropt" : ".*[^-+._$as_cr_alnum]" > /dev/null
./configure: line 1492:  3692 Segmentation fault      expr "x$ac_useropt" : ".*[^-+._$as_cr_alnum]" > /dev/null
./configure: line 1492:  3436 Segmentation fault      expr "x$ac_useropt" : ".*[^-+._$as_cr_alnum]" > /dev/null
checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2015-08-20, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;    f=config.guess;hb=HEAD
and
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD

If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please
send the following data and any information you think might be
pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2015-08-20

uname -m = x86
uname -r = 1
uname -s = WindowsNT
uname -v = 5

/usr/bin/uname -p =
/bin/uname -X     =

hostinfo               =
/bin/universe          =
/usr/bin/arch -k       =
/bin/arch              = i686
/usr/bin/oslevel       =
/usr/convex/getsysinfo =

UNAME_MACHINE = x86
UNAME_RELEASE = 1
UNAME_SYSTEM  = WindowsNT
UNAME_VERSION = 5
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

The [config.log](http://pastebin.com/NRsSdzH8) is here.

I also downdloaded the config.sub and config.guess
My OS is Windows XP SP3. The wxWidgets version is 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is very wrong with either the environment you're running configure in (Cygwin? MSYS? MSYS2? We don't know as you don't say) as `expr` definitely shouldn't segfault. Try running it interactively to see if you just have a corrupted `/usr/bin/expr` executable. If not, run hardware tests on your machine.

Comment: I use MSysGit with the UnixUtils (with the update) from sourceforge. As you said, the expr causes `Segmentation fault` [when use STRING : REGEXP](http://imgur.com/sO6uCjS), operator/ and match causes `syntax error`, the rest work normally.

Comment: I've downloaded the [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and replace the old files. Now the problem is solved, thanks!